# Google Coral Devboard PWR LED blinking

Tags: google-coral, google-developer-tools

I have a Google coral Devboard that I've been working on for the past few months. I plugged it in today and the PWR LED is blinking. No connection to the devboard is achievable, fan doesn't turn on, and using serial isn't working. Has anyone encountered this before? I do not have it connected to power intensive devices. The documentation does not say what blinking means.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I was first flashing Mendel onto the board with the environmental sensor board and camera module attached. After power cycling and changing boot to eMMC mode, the LED blinked and the fan twitched, but nothing more.

I resolved it by disconnecting both attachments; reconnecting the power source returned the board to normal behavior. Likely, it was a power or first boot issue (or a combination). Hope that helps in some way.

Comment: Could you send a link to the power cycling or procedure you followed?